# What is the proper way to delete a singly-linked-list in destructor?

Tags: c++, linked-list, destructor

Hello I have a bit ambiguity about writing a proper destructor:

```
class SLLst 
{
public:
    SLLst() = default;
    SLLst(const SLLst&);
    SLLst& operator=(SLLst);
    ~SLLst();

    void insert(int);
    void remove(int);

private:
    SLLst* next = nullptr;
    int data = 0;
    friend void swap(SLLst&, SLLst&);
    friend std::ostream& print(std::ostream&, const SLLst&);
};

SLLst::SLLst(const SLLst& rhs) : 
    next(rhs.next ? new SLLst() : nullptr),
    data(rhs.data)
{
    cout << "cpy-ctor" << endl;
}

SLLst& SLLst::operator=(SLLst rhs)
{
    cout << "operator=(SLLst)" << endl;
    using std::swap;
    swap(*this, rhs);
    return *this;
}

void swap(SLLst& lhs, SLLst& rhs)
{
    cout << "operator=(SLLst)" << endl;
    using std::swap;
    swap(lhs.next, rhs.next);
    swap(lhs.data, rhs.data);
}

SLLst::~SLLst()
{
    cout << "dtor" << endl;
    delete next;// is this enough?

    // or should I use this code?
    //SLLst* cur = next;
    //SLLst* n = nullptr;

    //while (cur != NULL) {
    //  n = cur->next;
    //  cur->next = nullptr;
    //  delete cur;
    //  cur = n;
    //}

}


void SLLst::insert(int x)
{
    SLLst* tmp = new SLLst();
    tmp->data = x;
    if (!next)
    {
        next = tmp;
        return;
    }

    tmp->next = next;
    next = tmp;
}

std::ostream& print(std::ostream& out, const SLLst& lst)
{
    auto tmp = lst.next;
    while (tmp)
    {
        out << tmp->data << ", ";
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    return out;
}
```

As you can see if I just use `delete next;` in destructor then I get it called as many as nodes in the list but why many implementations use a loop to free the nodes like the commented code in destructor?

- Because if I only call `delete` on `next` then the destructor will be called recursively thus I think I don't need a loop to free the nodes in destructor? is it correct?
- When should I use a loop to free nodes in destructor? Thank you!

*If I run my code I'll get:

81, 77, 57, 23, 16, 7, 5,

```
done
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
```

- As you can see dtor is called 8 times; does this mean it has properly freed all the nodes?

Comment: @JamesAdkison: But the destructor will be called on them all recursively I think.

Comment: I didn't look at your code but in the implementations that are using a loop those types don't have destructors, right? I'm guessing that is the difference in what you're doing and those examples.

Comment: Yes, it should recursively delete all its nodes.

Comment: Recursive deletion should be used with care. For long lists it can cause stack overflow.

Comment: @ChrisMM This is not the answer section.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0, I know, but that's hardly deserving of more than a comment. Just on mobile, so hard to type a full answer.

Comment: @ChrisMM Then you can just leave it to someone who has time to compose something more fully fleshed out. We need to be able to peer review solution suggestions (i.e. answers), length notwithstanding. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As you can see if I just use delete next; in destructor then I get it called as many as nodes in the list

Yep.

> Because if I only call delete on next then the destructor will be called recursively thus I think I don't need a loop to free the nodes in destructor? is it correct?

Yep.

> When should I use a loop to free nodes in destructor?

When you need to.

> but why many implementations use a loop to free the nodes like the commented code in destructor?

Because many implementations are "C-like", and do not use destructors. So they need to.

You are making the most of C++'s object management features to "do the loop for you". Yay!

(Although, to be honest, I would still do it in a loop, because your way is potentially quite stack-heavy.)

Now go one step further and switch to `std::list` (or `std::forward_list`).

Comment: std::forward_list, std::list is doubly linked

Comment: @JohnkaS Didn't mean to suggest it were functionally equivalent, but yeah ok

Comment: Thank you so much! really amazing and thorough explanation!

Comment: Yeah my favourite bit is "yep" :P

Comment: One last thing: Is loop more effective than recursive in this case? I mean as a matter of performance. (recursion overhead).

Comment: @JohnkaS: In  a real example I should use STL Containers like `forward_list` and `list`... but sometimes we should implement our own versions.

Comment: I can't think of any reason to implement your own linked list in C++. Regardless, you can measure the performance characteristics of these containers in your situations during different operations on your computer and decide for yourself what is best for you.

Comment: @Maestro done right there will be little to no performance difference between recursion and iteration. The recursion overhead is typically in the amount Automatic storage consumed. A long enough list will exhaust the stack (or whatever's backing Automatic storage) by storing `this` and the book-keeping information needed for finding the way back. Or maybe the compiler will see what you're doing and loop-ify the job for you. Compilers can be really smart if you let them. [See the Asif Rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule)

Answer (score 0):

Just immediately off the bat, std::unique_ptr would take care of this for you, but if you want to do it yourself, then it would look something like this, keep in mind this is a minimal example.

RAII is a very important principle in C++, it basically means, allocate when you need it, but destroy whenever you're done using it.

So if a node is being pointed to, and you delete the node that points to it, then that node should also destroy the thing it points to since it has ownership over it.

```cpp
class List {
    Node* first_node;

    ~List() {
        delete first_node;
    }

};

class Node {
    ~Node() {
        delete next; // will then in turn destroy the one it points to untill one is nullptr, deleting nullptr is well defined in C++ nowadays
    }
    Node* next;

};
```

Example with std::unique_ptr

```cpp
class List {
    std::unique_ptr<Node> first_node;

    // default dtor
};

class Node {
    std::unique_ptr<Node> next;
    // default dtor

};
```

Comment: An alternative approach wasn't requested; that's not the question

Comment: @Maestro, it's a good property. If you want to copy a list, you don't really want to copy pointers.

Comment: @Evg: I know using smart pointers is safer, quicker and less error-prone but for some educational reason we should practice more.

Comment: If you want to copy a linked list then you shouldn't copy the pointers, you should copy the content, so just implement a custom copy ctor that traverses the list and creates a new one, I actually believe that the Node class shouldn't be copied, but the List itself should, so that should handle it for you